# Kibud Av va’em & picking sides

Tags: children-parenting, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

In the case where two parents are going through a divorce, and one of the parents is abusive (emotionally), can one side with one parent over the other?

Is it better to stay silent, and not take sides, or to side with the correct parent?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Honoring Parents in Halacha by Rabbi Tzuriel Ta'aseh for a good collection of laws on this subject. There are two issues at play in your question.

1. When honouring parents, who comes first, mother or father?
2. When a parent is very difficult, what do we do?

For 1), generally speaking, the father comes first, even when divorced. However, during a divorce, if they ask simultaneously, one should try to please both at the same time, and if they can't, one is free to pick.

Other times when one can listen to one's mother first:

- When the father expects one to do something that will incur personal
  expenses, and the mother says not to, then one may listen to their
  mother.
- If one knows one's father doesn't want them to do something but he
  never said it out loud, and his mother asks him to do it, then they can do it.
- If one's mother asks them for something, like a drink, and the father says not to do it, one may do it.
- One may not respond to a request to reveal information that will anger the father about the mother.
- If the parents are both poor, the child brings clothing to the mother first.
- If one's parents are divorced, and the father wants one to do something that the mother would find greatly disturbing, one should sit tight.

When it comes to having a very difficult relationship with one parent, page 22, inyan 22:

> The mitzvah of kibbud av va'em applies even if the parents are strict and demanding. However, if the parents are very difficult people and constantly cause their child distress, he should move away from them. It is always proper in such cases to seek competent halachic advice.

That last line on competent halachic advise is the perfect place to end this answer: unifying the above halachot into a specific case can and should only be done by a competent halachic authority, ideally one who knows one best.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "side" with "the correct parent", based on what the Talmud says:

> It is a mitzvah to divorce an evil wife. [Eruvin 41b]

> A man who brings up an evil name [on his wife] is flogged and must pay a hundred sela. [Eruvin 45b]

In the long run, however, you are still obligated to honor both parents.

Comment: "_It is a mitzvah to divorce an evil wife. [Eruvin 41b]_" (1) What if the husband is evil? (2) What if before the divorce the couple was merely incompatible, and one side only "became evil" ("emotionally abusive" in the words of the question) during the divorce proceedings (like when arguing over custody, or financial arrangements)? (3) What bearing does that have on the son, who is not [necessarily] affected by the parent's evil, and is generally obligated in honoring both them?

Comment: "_A man who brings up an evil name [on his wife] is flogged and must pay a hundred sela. [Eruvin 45b]_" Yet he is not forced to divorce his wife?